# nohup doesn't write anything to file

Tags: java, linux, nohup

i have a Java program which executes the following shell script to restart it self.

```
sleep 5
nohup java -jar /home/my-dir/MyJar.jar &
```

If i run the script from a terminal, it just works as expected. However if the Java Program executes the script, the program starts normally but nothing gets written to the output file.

I start the script via the following code

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("/bin/sh", "/home/my-dir/start.sh");
try {
    processBuilder.start();
    logger.info("Successfully started");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You should use the absolute path of the jar in your script.

Comment: @Olivier The problem persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following command worked for me. It writes all the output to the specified file.

```
nohup java -jar /home/my-dir/MyJar.jar > /home/my-dir/log.txt & tail -f /home/my-dir/log.txt &
```